# Show that it is impossible that $P(a)=b$, $P(b)=c$, and $P(c)=a$ at the same time.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let $a, b, c$ be distinct integers, and let $P$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Show that it is impossible that $P(a)=b$, $P(b)=c$, and $P(c)=a$ at the same time.

Comment: What would the constant term of $P$ be under these conditions?

Comment: I took some time posting my solution, I just wanted to share this problem with you guys. :)

Comment: I request you to accept an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 2):

.Hint : By the remainder theorem, $P(x) - P(y)$ is divisible by $x-y$, for all $x,y$.

Assume that $a < b < c$, since they are distinct, and see that putting $x=c,y=a$ gives that $c-a$ divides $a-b$. Now, can you see the problem with this statement?

Answer (score 1):

Assume otherwise.

By the remainder theorem, $a-b$ divides $b-c$, $b-c$ divides $c-a$, and $c-a$ divides $a-b$.

Then, $b-c$ also divides $a-b$, therefore, $2a = b+c$.

$c-a$ also divides $b-c$, therefore $2c = a+b$

Substracting both equations:

$2(a-c) = -(a-c)$

$a-c=0$

$a=c$

Contradiction! Therefore, we are done.

Comment: Your proof and mine are  almost the same, but yours looks nicer, so $+1$.